# How is the manipulation is done on bit level?

Tags: c++, binary, logic

Assume that the size of char is 1 byte and negatives are stored in 2's complement form

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c = 125;
    c = c+10;
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

How can be the answer is -121?

Comment: Try writing 125, 135, and -121 on paper as 8-bit binary values.  It should be very clear what's happening.  Do you know what 2's complement means?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default and: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

125 + 10 = 135. This is above 127, hence the addition overflows and the end result is 135 - 256 = - 121.

Comment: What is the significance of the number `127` for chars?

Comment: @JohnOdom  its 2^7 - 1.  since one bit is used for the sign 127 is the max a singed char can represent.

Comment: @NathanOliver John Odom is maybe being kind of pedantic but the point he's making is technically correct (The best kind of correct).  Nothing forces a char to be an 8-bit value.

Comment: @PeteBaughman Nathan doesn't say that it's _forced_ to be an 8 bit value. Just that it _is_. John may be thinking of other languages, such as Java or C#.

Comment: @MrLister: I believe it would be different platforms.  Different platforms can have different `char` bits.  The CDC Cyber uses a 6/12 bit scheme, 6 bits for popular things, 12 bits for extended.